# Pandas groupby: checking gaps within a group

Tags: python, pandas

This is my data frame, If there is a gap in Year for a particular name, Gap column should be True else False.

```
Name    Year       Gap
A       2008      False
A       2008      False
A       2009      True
A       2011      False
B       2010      True 
B       2013      False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df['Gap'] = df.groupby('Name')['Year'].diff(-1).lt(-1)
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: Year, dtype: bool
```

Comment: thank you so much. Can you please explain what diff(-1).lt(-1) does?

Comment: @vicky `diff(-1)` takes the difference with the next row, `lt(-1)` is `less than -1`, indicating a jump in the values.